# escape character with ssh

Tags: ssh, escaping, character

I'm trying to write several commands trought ssh connection bue I got problem with escape characters. Below an example of what I'd like to do:

```
/usr/bin/ssh mrtg@172.20.29.40 echo -e "ciao\nprova"
```

I got this result:

```
ciaonprova
```

instead of:

```
ciao
prova
```

if I use `-e` option for ssh:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -e mrtg@172.20.29.40  echo -e 'ciao\nprova'
```

I receive this error:

```
Bad escape character 'mrtg@172.20.29.40'.
```

Can someone give me a suggestion to let remote server interpret escape characters?

Answer (score 2):

The `-e` option has nothing to do with your command (these are SSH escape characters, not shell).

You can just put your command in quotes:

```
/usr/bin/ssh mrtg@172.20.29.40 'echo -e "ciao\nprova"'
```